# Android and iPhone app automation tools

Tags: android, automation, software-testing, iphone-app

Please suggest me tools for Android and iPhone app automation testing. I have searched some, like - Appium, Calabash, MonkeyTalk, Selendroid, Robotium, etc.

But, I am confused to choose any one. Please assist me in choosing best automation testing tool so that I can start with better tool which should have following-

1. Works for Android and iPhone as well.( Android is highly needed, iPhone is optional).
2. Support for Continuous Integration.
3. Tool should be Open Source (Free).
4. Supported scripting language should have Java.
5. Community should be active.

Answer (score 4):

[Bharat Mane’s answer (on Software Quality Assurance & Testing SE)](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/a/18329/):

> There are number of tools available in the market like:-
>
> a) Robotium b) Uiautomator c) Espresso d) Appium e) Calabash
>
> But my experience -I can suggest you **Appium** is the best tool for both Android & iOS mobile testing. I'm working on appium from last 6 months in my organization it is pretty good.
>
> The main **advantages of using Appium** is-
>
> 1. Cross-platform
> 2. Backend is Selenium so you will get all selenium functionality
> 3. Able to test iOS and Android
> 4. Continuous integration support
> 5. Doesn't require access to your source code or library. You are
>      testing which you will actually ship.
> 6. supports multiple frameworks.
> 7. Supports automation of hybris, native and webapps.
> 8. Open source (free)
> 9. Can run app through appium server without manipulating the app.
> 10. No source code required(unlike robotium)
> 11. CI compatible with jenkins, saucelabs(so far from my experience)
>        Able to run on selenium grid.
> 12. Doesn't require an APK for use, although automating certain apps
>
> There is also few Disadvantages of Appium:
>
> For Android, No Support for Android API level < 17. It means you want to use Android v-4.2 or greater version.
>
> [image: Table comparing Robotium, Uiautomator, Espresso, Appium, and Calabash]