# An app to run iPhone apps on Mac

Tags: osx, iphone-app, emulator

I'm looking for macOS app to run or play iPhone apps/games in simulated environment. Similar to [BlueStacks](http://www.bluestacks.com/) for Android apps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are few suggestions:

- [iPadian](http://www.ipadian.net/mac.html) ($20)

  > iOS Simulator for MacOS based on Adobe AIR. It supports iPhone and iPad apps.
- Simulator (free)

  > iPhone/iPad Simulator is available within Xcode (available to download), but it can be run as a separate app on its own. See: [Getting Started in Simulator](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/iOS_Simulator_Guide/GettingStartedwithiOSSimulator/GettingStartedwithiOSSimulator.html).

For apps designed for automation, see: [Android and iPhone app automation tools](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/31704/3474).